Options for dual-booting 2+ Ubuntu-based distros/flavours installed on the same disk
On a standard UEFI/GPT system, there is normally only one EFI system partition (ESP) per disk and OS installers put their bootloaders there. Ubuntu-based distros/flavours (Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Mint, etc.) tend to use the same folder name (EFI/ubuntu) and so the last installed will typically overwrite its contents. From what I've read, the last one is supposed to detect the other ones and configure boot menu entries for them automatically, but my experience suggests otherwise.
What are the practical implications from having a shared ESP EFI/ubuntu and what options are there to configure (or fix) dual-boot/multi-boot with two or more such operating systems?

When we install an OS, the installer will put it in one or more dedicated partitions. However, it will also install a bootloader and a part of it (the "entry point") will be written to the shared EFI system partition (ESP). In Linux the ESP is usually mounted at /boot/efi or /efi (you can easily check that in /etc/fstab or with tools like df and lsblk). Usually it's between 100 MB and 1 GB.
Most Linux distros nowadays are shipped with the GRUB bootloader. Technically, GRUB is also a boot manager (i.e. it can show a menu of options to the user when the computer starts).
Let's first start with an example of a setup where each OS has its own folder in the ESP under EFI/:

When we install a new OS, it might detect other existing operating systems and automatically add additional boot menu entries for them in its config files (typically /boot/grub/grub.cnf for Ubuntu or /boot/grub2/grub.cnf for Fedora).
There are two main ways "foreign" boot menu entries are defined:

GRUB "calls" the bootloader of the other OS. That's called chainloading and is what GRUB would do, for example, if it needs to boot Windows (its bootloader would reside in EFI/Microsoft/ in ESP).
GRUB directly loads the respective (Linux) OS. For example, a Fedora's /boot/grub2/grub.cnf might have a menuentry for Kubuntu that directly runs linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-31-generic root=UUID=7d22a..., etc.

Let's say, we first install Ubuntu and then Fedora. The Fedora installer will "see" Ubuntu and can add menu entries in its /boot/grub2/grub.cnf file for Ubuntu. At that point Ubuntu's bootloader will not know about Fedora, but if we update Ubuntu's GRUB /boot/grub/grub.cnf (via the update-grub command, or the equivalent grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg), Ubuntu will "see" Fedora and will add entries for Fedora.
However, if we install multiple "ubuntu" operating systems, they will "compete" for the same ESP EFI/ubuntu spot. Typically, the last one will overwrite its contents. The EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg file in particular will be changed from something like this:
search.fs_uuid 9c2e8025-89a1-476a-9d48-aad187ab96c7 root
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

to something like this:
search.fs_uuid 5d262996-46d5-416e-ab7d-35a54179bf0a root
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

Let's visualize that:

In that example, the "ubuntu" GRUB will try to find the device (partition) with the specified UUID and will go to its config file. Note that the path in the second line might look a bit different if you've set up LVM with LUKS encryption, because you would have a separate small non-encrypted partition that would get mounted as /boot (instead of /). Just something to be aware of.
Ideally, after the last "ubuntu" installation, its /boot/grub/grub.cnf should contain menu entries for all other operating systems as well. But that doesn't always seem to be the case. Moreover, at some point you might want to ditch that OS or not be dependent on it for managing the bootloading process of the other OSs.
Quick switch (from ESP)
You can manually modify the first 1 or 2 lines in EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg, so that it points to another "ubuntu" instance. If you rarely need to switch between those operating systems, that in itself could work just fine. If you happen to mess something up, don't worry - just boot from another (non "ubuntu") OS (if present) or from a "live USB" and modify the file.
A quick tip (comments)
These config files support comments, so instead of looking for the UUID (via blkid, lsblk -f, etc.) and copy-pasting it every time, you can add all your entries in the file and just comment/uncomment lines by adding/removing a single #. Example:
# My main Ubuntu 24.04
search.fs_uuid 9c2e8025-89a1-476a-9d48-aad187ab96c7 root

# The Kubuntu 24.04 that I use for testing
# search.fs_uuid 5d262996-46d5-416e-ab7d-35a54179bf0a root

set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

Modifying one of the OS's GRUB config
You can pick one of the installed "ubuntu" instances and set up menu entries for all Linux instances (but make sure EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg points to it).
The update-grub/grub-mkconfig tool can be configured to do that automatically for you, by scanning the other partitions. If that's what you want, add GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false to /etc/default/grub.
However, there are some potential problems with that approach:

From my experience, sometimes it won't detect all operating systems. I suspect that it might have a problem with LVM/LUKS encrypted ones. Not sure why - those have a separate /boot partition that isn't encrypted, so it should be able to read its GRUB config.
Whenever a Linux upgrades its kernel, it will also call grub-mkconfig to update its boot menu entries. However, if you use OS 1 for booting but upgrade OS 2, OS 1 might not know that its "foreign" menu entries aren't valid anymore (they might "point" to an old 6.8.0-29-generic for example). You can, of course, then enter OS 1 and update its GRUB config and the "foreign" menu entries for OS 2 should get updated. But that's not ideal.

Multiple menu entries in the ESP config
I've found I can just list multiple menuentry sections in the EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg file directly, like this:
menuentry 'Kubuntu 23.10' - class os $menuentry_id_option 'ubu-id-1' {
    search.fs_uuid 9c2e8025-89a1-476a-9d48-aad187ab96c7 root
    set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
    configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
}
menuentry 'Xubuntu 24.04' - class os $menuentry_id_option 'ubu-id-2' {
    search.fs_uuid 5d262996-46d5-416e-ab7d-35a54179bf0a root
    set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
    configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
}

So every time my UEFI boots from EFI/ubuntu, a menu is displayed and I can choose whichever OS I want.

That option might have its limitations, but the main advantages I see are:

Simpler flow. We don't have to depend on one particular OS's /boot/grub/grub.cnf config to give us the boot menu options.
No hardcoded versions/params. Each OS knows its own config best and doesn't have to keep track of what was updated on the others.

Alternative boot managers
rEFInd is a popular alternative boot manager that scans your partitions, finds the available operating systems, and presents you with a menu of options at boot time. It's quite easy to install and try. Similarly to other boot managers, it will create its own folder in ESP, called EFI/refind.

I prefer to turn off os-prober and add the boot stanzas to 40_custom. Best not to directly edit grub.cfg in install. I used to edit UUID in grub.cfg in ESP, but find it easier just to do a sudo grub-install after booting into preferred install. Major grub updates will reset that install to first, so you do have to manage who is first. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392441&p=13816046#post13816046
Using 40_custom & Custom menu
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus  You do need every install in 40_custom for other installs, in case you need to boot them on reset.

Good writeup. I tend to use systemd-boot lately, which is not as arcane and baroque as grub. With a directory of systemd on the ESP (UEFI) partition besides the EFI directory and separate loader files in /loader/entries/Ubuntu.conf, you can boot all Linuxes, Windows, the EFI shell and a lot more just with a couple of simple, short text files.

However, it will also install a bootloader and a part of it (the "entry point") will be written to the shared EFI system partition (ESP). Except in my case I have two /EFI partitions and bother have been saved in the UEFI of my system. I can now bring up the UEFI boot menu to load one or the other. Will I have to delete one of the EFI partitions and start one installation again?

@JohnK.N. Are you sure you have 2 ESPs on the same disk? What OS(s) do you have installed on that disk and do you want to keep them or reinstall? Perhaps you should post a separate question with more details (incl. output of lsblk -f).

Will do thanks.

I posted a question over on Unix & Linux seeing as my distros are not related to Ubuntu.
